# Loop versus order of operations

Tags: c++, loops

vec is a custom class of vector with a current value of (4,0,0), and _vec is a vector with a current value of (1,0,0).

The operator-= has been overloaded so that vector[i]=vector[i]-rhs.vector[i]

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
    vec-= _vec;
}
if(vec==_vec){
    return true;
}
```

if I use this code, the function returns true, and vec[0] is shown to be 1

```
((vec-= _vec) -= _vec) -= _vec;
if(vec==_vec){
    return true;
}
```

However, when I use this code, the function returns false, and vec[0] seems to be 3. 
Aren't these two codes supposed to do the same thing? I don't quite understand why the latter fails to work.

Comment: What does your `vec -= _vec` return?

Comment: the operator-= is set to return *this. Going through the debug compiler shows that the vec is being subtracted all the way to 1 with each time -=_vec is called, but at the end, the line seems to return vec = 3,0,0

Comment: Hmmm...what happens if you remove the parentheses? Compiler gripe?

Comment: Oh, the x is declared as a constant variable, so it won't let me remove the parentheses from the line.

Comment: `x`? What is `x`?

Comment: x is a constant vector of the same class as vec. It has been instantiated with a value of 1,0,0. Oh I meant to write _vec instead of x. wrote the wrong thing there.

Comment: I have found the problem. Looks like I had forgotten the compound assignment operator to return a reference. Added that and it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Always nice to help someone else who knows what Slant Walk is. Bob Jarvis, Miami U '79  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're subtracting `_vec` from `vec` four times.

In the second example you're only invoking `operator::-=` three times, so that's one thing. More importantly, it appears that a temporary object is being created so that `*this` isn't what you think it is. Printing out `this` in `operator::-=` would help to confirm this.

Best of luck.